# Manually Assigning WCF Application in IIS

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wcf, iis, iis-7, iis-7.5

In a Visual Studio "WCF Service Application" project, on the properties->web page, if I select "Use Local IIS Web Server"->"create virtual directory"...it creates the IIS application successfully in the Default Web Site of a local IIS 7.5 install.  So far so good.

However, I'd like to use a site other than the default web site.  My attempts to host the service in a different web site aren't working.  I tried:

1. Delete the application / virtual directory in IIS that Visual Studio successfully created.
2. Manually create a new IIS application, in the different web site, using the same settings that were present in the IIS application previously created by Visual Studio automatically.
3. Go to Visual Studio, project properties->web, and select the "visual studio development server".  Save.  This is just an "erase" step.
4. On the same properties page, I select "Use Local IIS Web Server" again and hit save (without pressing "Create Virtual Directory").

In that last step, I expect it to save.  It doesn't.  It pops up a message saying the virtual directory does not exist.  But as I stated, it does exist because I had manually created it just prior.

My own guesses about this problem:

*. The non-default site I've made is somehow different from the default web site, in a way I've yet to determine.
 *. Visual Studio is not designed to work with a virtual directory that is not in the default web site.

Any suggestions or clarifications?

I've activated IIS "failed request tracing," but no records are created for this issue.

Comment: Just to clarify, you are attempting to use a different website than the default site but still hosted on the same IIS server as the default site that works correctly, correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is look at your second site is IIS (the one you want the WCF service to run under) and look at the host name on new or if you go to manage web site -> advanced settings and look at what is after the the bindings.  So it may show something like: http:*:80:localhost2 .  localhost2 is what you need.  It may be an IP Address too, not sure how you set it up.

So then in your WCF project properties in the Use Local IIS Server -> Project URL you put the host name of the site. So for example it may be something like:  `http://localhost2/yourservice.svc` .

Comment: I figured it out: http://www.ariasamp.net/2012/09/asp-net-debugging-pick-your-iis-site/